# Using GSL Monte Carlo Integration in C++ for a multidimensional function

Tags: c++, montecarlo, gsl, numerical-integration

I'm trying to use GSL Monte Carlo Integration in a C++ code that I'm generating.
The idea would be to have a brownian motion function (`brownian`), which is used in another function (`g`) for performing 4-dim numerical integration.

```
double brownian(const double &x,const double &x0,const double & sigma,const double & t) {
   double a1 = (1/sqrt(2.0 * M_PI * sigma * t));
   double b1 = exp(-((x - x0) * (x - x0))/(2.0 * sigma * t));
   double res = a1 * b1;
  return res;
}

double g(double *k, size_t dim, void *p[]){

 const double& xA0 = *(double *)p[0];
 const double& xB0 = *(double *)p[1];
 const double& yA0 = *(double *)p[2];
 const double& yB0 = *(double *)p[3];
 const double& sigma = *(double *)p[4];
 const double& t1 = *(double *)p[5];


  double temp_pbxA = brownian(k[0], xA0, sigma,t1);
  double temp_pbxB = brownian(k[1], xB0, sigma, t1);
  double temp_pbyA = brownian(k[2], yA0, sigma,t1);
  double temp_pbyB = brownian(k[3], yB0, sigma, t1);

  return (temp_pbxB * temp_pbyB) * (temp_pbxA * temp_pbyA);
}

double integrate_test(const double xl, const double xu, const double& xA0, const double& xB0, const double& yA0, const double& yB0, const double& t1, const double& sigma){

  double res, err;

 const gsl_rng_type *T;
  gsl_rng *r;

  gsl_monte_function G;
  G.f = &g;
  G.dim = 4;
  G.params = { xA0, xB0, yA0, yB0, sigma, t1};

  size_t calls = 500000;

  gsl_rng_env_setup ();

  T = gsl_rng_default;
  r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);


    gsl_monte_plain_state *s = gsl_monte_plain_alloc (4);
    gsl_monte_plain_integrate (&G, xl, xu, 4, calls, r, s,
                               &res, &err);
    gsl_monte_plain_free (s);

return res;
    }
```

However, when I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
error: assigning to 'double (*)(double *, size_t, void *)' (aka 'double (*)(double *, unsigned long, void *)') from incompatible type 'double (*)(double *, size_t, void **)' (aka 'double (*)(double *, unsigned long, void **)'): type mismatch at 3rd parameter ('void *' vs 'void **')
  G.f = &g;
```

I do not understand why it takes the `void *p[]` as it was a `void**`.
Any suggestion?

Comment: *I do not understand why it takes the void p[]* -- Look at your code carefully:  `double g(double *k, size_t dim, void *p[])` -- That is a `void* p[]`, and not `void p[]`.

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in my typing. What I meant was why it takes the void *p[] as if was a  void ** object.

Comment: That's how C++ works.  A `T*[]` as a parameter is the same as `T**`, regardless what `T` is.

Comment: Ok, clear. But then, if I want that the void *p is an array of several parameters for the function g, what should I specify?

Comment: First, why did you design `g` to take a `void*`?  There are much better type-safe ways to implement this.  Looks like you're stepping into [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) territory.

Comment: Because g will be used as a function for the gsl_monte_function that I create within 'integrate_test' function. In particular, gsl_monte_function is defined as a double (* f) (double * x, size_t dim, void * params) function. I hope it is clear. I'm quite new in C++.

Comment: Why did you come up with your own rules when you created `g` if you know the function pointer from the library accepts `void *`?  If the library function takes a `void *`, then it takes a `void *`.   You can't just simply circumvent this with your own idea of what should be done.  Even the compiler isn't letting you get away with doing this.  That's why I mentioned that it looks like an XY problem.

Comment: because I did not know that p[] would have been 'considered' as a void **. This is why in my last comments I also wrote: if I want that the void *p is an array of several parameters for the function g, what should I specify?

Comment: Have you considered simply passing a pointer to a struct that has those parameters?  Then you are passing a single item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237055/discussion-between-caffesospeso-and-paulmckenzie).

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre], with all header files etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a diff between your code and the one that compiles. This does not mean that my code is correct: you only get what you asked for - since you did not  provide a complete minimum working example, anyone trying to help you is forced to guess what your problem really is.

```
13c13
< double g(double *k, size_t dim, void *p){
---
> double g(double *k, size_t dim, void *p[]){
15,20c15,20
<  const double& xA0 = ((double *)p)[0];
<  const double& xB0 = ((double *)p)[1];
<  const double& yA0 = ((double *)p)[2];
<  const double& yB0 = ((double *)p)[3];
<  const double& sigma = ((double *)p)[4];
<  const double& t1 = ((double *)p)[5];
---
>  const double& xA0 = *(double *)p[0];
>  const double& xB0 = *(double *)p[1];
>  const double& yA0 = *(double *)p[2];
>  const double& yB0 = *(double *)p[3];
>  const double& sigma = *(double *)p[4];
>  const double& t1 = *(double *)p[5];
31c31
< double integrate_test(const double xl[], const double xu[], const double& xA0, const double& xB0, const double& yA0, const double& yB0, const double& t1, const double& sigma){
---
> double integrate_test(const double xl, const double xu, const double& xA0, const double& xB0, const double& yA0, const double& yB0, const double& t1, const double& sigma){
41,42c41
<   double params[] = { xA0, xB0, yA0, yB0, sigma, t1};
<   G.params = params;
---
>   G.params = { xA0, xB0, yA0, yB0, sigma, t1};
```

As you can see, there are at least 2 problems that your compiler complains about.

1. `gsl_monte_function` expect the component `f` to have the signature `double (* f) (double * x, size_t dim, void * params)`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/montecarlo.html . I must stress that normally parameters in GSL are passed via a void pointer to struct that must be defined somewhere beforehand, but here you're lucky, all parameters are just `double`s, so to save extra code you can use an old, plain C array

```
double params[] = { xA0, xB0, yA0, yB0, sigma, t1};
```

and pass  its address as the `G.params`. Then you'll retrieve them inside `g` using C-syntax like this

```
const double& xA0 = ((double *)p)[0];
```

(convert the void pointer to `double*` and then treat it as a name of a C-style array).

2. `gsl_monte_plain_integrate` expects its 2nd and 3rd parameters to be C-style arrays. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/montecarlo.html .  That's why you need to change the  types of `xl` and `xu` in `integrate_test`.

GSL **is hard** to use. Don't hesitate to ask if in doubt.

Comment: Better use `static_cast<double*>(p)[0]` rather than the C-style cast, since we're in C++.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes. Also, references in expressions like `const double& xA0` are unnecessary, and some other improvements are possible, like defining `params` as `std::array` etc., but all documentation of GSL is written in C, so  I basically followed this style.